# Is there a way to flag Facebook posts so I can look at them later?

Tags: facebook

I like to skim through my Facebook newsfeed and flag posts (and sometimes links) I want to read then come back and read that stuff. (I find this is less distracting and I'm less likely to lose an hour down a rat hole.)

Comment: To ask about doing this on Android, you really should ask instead at [android.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sometimes share the post I want to come back to on my own wall... but I set the "Who should see this?" to "Only Me".
come back later and delete when done.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to links that get posted, there is the [Save](http://newsroom.fb.com/news/2014/07/introducing-save-on-facebook/) feature that you can use.

Comment: I think the "Save" button, only works for Link type posts. For another solution that should work with any type of Facebook post, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to click the "**Share**" link beneath the post, then select "**In a private message**" then start typing out your Full Facebook name, and you can then send the link to the post as a private message to yourself, that you can check later. Note the "Save" button method that Alex mentioned only works for Link type posts, using the "Share" method should work for any FB post.

Comment: I do not see "in a private message" on my android phone, but I can post to my Wall and set it to visible ONLY to ME.  If you want to update your answer I'll accept that.

Comment: you didn't mention in your post that you were on an android phone. though having said that i only just noticed that you have tagged it android, you probably should have mentioned it in the post tho as its clearer that way. BTW on my android phone, using the mobile web site, i do get the option to "Send as message" when i click the share button. I think they have a progressively enhanced mobile site, which means they show different versions of the site to clients with different capabilities, better devices get more advanced versions and options.